# SQL - Output every possible relation of 2 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, left-join, inner-join

I apologize for the ambiguity of the title. If anyone has a better suggestion after reading this I will gracefully change it.

I have 2 tables:

DEPT table (departments):

```
|IDDEPT |  DEPTNAME  |
--------+------------+
| 10    | ACCOUNTING |
| 20    | RESEARCH   |    
| 30    | OPERATIONS |
--------+------------+
```

EMP table (employees):

```
| IDEMP |  EMPNAME  |  MGR  | IDDEPT |
--------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 7001  |   SMITH   | 7007  | 10     |
| 7002  |   ALLEN   | 7006  | 10     |
| 7003  |   WARD    | 7006  | 20     |
| 7004  |   JONES   | 7006  | 20     |
| 7005  |   MARTIN  | 7007  | 10     |
| 7006  |   BLAKE   | 7008  | 20     |
| 7007  |   FORD    | 7008  | 10     |
| 7008  |   KING    | NULL  | 10     |
--------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

MGR column is the employee's manager identifier. KING has a NULL because he is the director of the company. IDDEPT on EMP table is the department the employees belong to.

What I am trying to do is, for each manager (KING, FORD and BLAKE in this scenario), show the number of employees they supervise on each department (10, 20 and 30).

For this given scenario, the output I'm trying to obtain (not strictly this order) would be as follows:

```
| IDEMP |  EMPNAME  | IDDEPT |  N_EMPLOYEES_SUPERVISED  |
--------+-----------+--------+--------------------------+
| 7006  |   BLAKE   | 10     | 1                        |
| 7006  |   BLAKE   | 20     | 2                        |
| 7006  |   BLAKE   | 30     | 0                        |
| 7007  |   FORD    | 10     | 2                        |
| 7007  |   FORD    | 20     | 0                        |
| 7007  |   FORD    | 30     | 0                        |
| 7008  |   KING    | 10     | 1                        |
| 7008  |   KING    | 20     | 1                        |
| 7008  |   KING    | 30     | 0                        |
--------+-----------+--------+--------------------------+
```

However, I am not able to output the rows where the count is 0.

Comment: Definition: a relation is *reflexive* if for every *x* in the underlying set, *x* is in relation with itself. Obviously your relation is **not** reflexive. Other than that - usually a department head "supervises" all the employees in that department, not just those that report to him or her *directly*. Do you only need the number of **direct** reports from each department?

Comment: Right. Yes, this is a personal task I'm doing myself to improve my SQL. I thought it this way but could have totally been like you present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `cross join` the employees tables with the list of departments, then bring the original table with a `left join`. To restrict the results to employees that are managers, we can use `exists`:

```
select m.idemp, m.empname, d.iddept, 
    count(e.idemp) as n_employees_supervised
from emp m
cross join dept d 
left join emp e on e.mgr = m.idemp and e.iddept = d.iddept
where exists (select 1 from emp e1 where e1.mgr = m.idemp)
group by m.idemp, m.empname, d.iddept
```

An alternative that avoids the `exists` subquery is conditional aggregation:

```
select m.idemp, m.empname, d.iddept, 
    sum(case when e.iddept = d.iddept then 1 else 0 end) as n_employees_supervised
from emp m
cross join dept d 
inner join emp e on e.mgr = m.idemp
group by m.idemp, m.empname, d.iddept
```

Comment: It works great. Now I understand why I was using wrong the cross join, thank you! For your curiosity, the query I had before the post was very similar to your first one, but I wasn't joining the 'emp e' with the iddept column... Also, I was using a subquery to specify the employees that are managers: 'where m.idemp in (select mgr from emp)'

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query to descend the `EMP` hierarchy 2 levels and then use a partitioned outer join on the `DEPT` table before aggregating (and only selects from `EMP` and `DEPT` once each):

```sql
SELECT e.idemp,
       e.empname,
       d.iddept,
       COUNT( e.iddept )
FROM   DEPT d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( IDEMP   ) AS IDEMP,
                CONNECT_BY_ROOT( EMPNAME ) AS EMPNAME,
                IDDEPT
         FROM   EMP e
         WHERE  LEVEL = 2
         CONNECT BY PRIOR IDEMP = MGR
       ) e
       PARTITION BY ( e.IDEMP, e.EMPNAME )
       ON ( e.IDDEPT = d.IDDEPT )
GROUP BY
       e.idemp,
       e.empname,
       d.iddept;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEPT ( IDDEPT, DEPTNAME ) AS
SELECT 10, 'ACCOUNTING' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'RESEARCH'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 'OPERATIONS' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE EMP ( IDEMP, EMPNAME, MGR, IDDEPT ) AS
SELECT 7001, 'SMITH',  7007, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7002, 'ALLEN',  7006, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7003, 'WARD',   7006, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7004, 'JONES',  7006, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7005, 'MARTIN', 7007, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7006, 'BLAKE',  7008, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7007, 'FORD',   7008, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7008, 'KING',   NULL, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> IDEMP | EMPNAME | IDDEPT | COUNT(E.IDDEPT)
> ----: | :------ | -----: | --------------:
>  7006 | BLAKE   |     10 |               1
>  7006 | BLAKE   |     20 |               2
>  7006 | BLAKE   |     30 |               0
>  7007 | FORD    |     10 |               2
>  7007 | FORD    |     20 |               0
>  7007 | FORD    |     30 |               0
>  7008 | KING    |     10 |               1
>  7008 | KING    |     20 |               1
>  7008 | KING    |     30 |               0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7f06f0f922473b7f32183abe1a43ebb)*

Comment: This works if the hierarchy is three levels deep, as it is in the OP's sample data. If it's deeper than that, the query will return the number of direct reports for all levels of managers, not just for the "director" and the department heads.

Comment: @mathguy  The OP wanted it "for each manager"; they said nothing about wanting to restrict it to just the top 2 levels of the management chain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example MT0, I didn't even know there was such a thing as CONNECT_BY_ROOT...